# Save UITableView's selected row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, selected, nsuinteger

I have two UITableViews. I want to know how to "save" the selected row in the first table view to be able to use that number as a index for showing that specific index in my other table view. It uses a plist to store an array with arrays with dictionaries.

Here is what I am trying to use now:

```
mycontroller.selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row;
```

`selectedIndexPath` is a NSUInteger. But is doesn't really work. Any suggestions for a solution? Thanks.

Comment: what is mycontroller.selectedIndexPath? Maybe you should just to create a private NSIndexPath variable?

Comment: It is a NSUInteger in another view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Code as follows :-

First of all ,you are doing a wrong thing in your question , it should be as follows

```
myController.selectedIndexpath.row = indexpath.row
```

**first option :-** 
To store the row of selectedIndexPath , you can store it as `userDefaults`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"selectedRow"];
```

And use it in the `SecondTableView`

```
index =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"selectedRow"];
```

**second option:-**

```
use `@property`
```